# Jinja templates in ansible loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to run an ansible loop based on input from a CSV file. I am using the following question / [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014600/how-to-iterate-csv-file-in-ansible) as reference. However, I cannot seem to figure out where to actually include the jinja part for the loop.

So far this is what I have, but it throws an error:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    csv_var: "{{ lookup ('file', 'file.csv') }}"

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - {% set list = csv_var.split(",") %}
```

`file.csv` has the following content: `345,1234,1234`

Ideally the message should print out the numbers above.

The syntax error I was getting is:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    with_items:
      - {% set list = csv_var.split(",") %}
         ^ here

exception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
exception: while scanning for the next token
found character that cannot start any token
  in "<unicode string>", line 19, column 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Jinja2 expression not a statement.

You should also quote any string that starts with `{` in Ansible:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ csv_var.split(',') }}"
```

<sup>And there is no need to wrap the resulting list in another list (dash before element), although Ansible handles this automatically.</sup>